# OpenMP segfaults when arrays are not allocatable during parallel random number generation

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am currently learning to use OpenMP with Fortran, and as practice I tried to generate two large arrays of random reals and multiply them together. The first thing I tried to do was to generate the arrays in parallel. Here I encountered a perplexing issue. At first my code looked like this:

```
program omp_test
use omp_lib
implicit none

!Variable definitions.
integer,parameter :: n=1000 !Matrix size.
real*8,dimension(n,n) :: A,B !Matrices.
integer :: row,col !Loop variables.

write(*,*) "Before OMP assignment."

!Parallel loop to assign a random number to every element in A and B.
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
do row = 1,n
    do col=1,n
        A(row,col)=rand()
        B(row,col)=rand()
    end do 
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

write(*,*) "After OMP assignment."

end program omp_test
```

This code (compiled with gfortran and -fopenmp -O3 flags) results in the output

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and nothing else, not even a backtrace. If I change the matrix size to 512x512 it still crashes the same way, but 511x511 works fine (changing OMP_STACKSIZE does not seem to help). It also works fine if I omit the -fopenmp flag during compilation. Note that not even the write statement executes. If I remove the assignment loop, or remove the OMP flags there are no problems, so the existance of the loop causes the program to crash before it reaches the loop. However, if I change the A and B assignment in the beginning to

```
real*8,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: A,B
```

and allocate them directly after the first write statement with

```
allocate(A(n,n))
allocate(B(n,n))
```

it runs fine for all matrix sizes. I suspect rand()s use of SAVE might be the culprit somehow, but I do not understand why it would work for allocatable arrays if that was the issue.

Does anyone know what the issue is and how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe not your issue - but `rand` is not generally thread safe. Typically it will either result in bad numbers or very bad performance.

Comment: We have many duplicates about static arrays and openmp.

Comment: There are dedicated parallel random number generators. And questions and answers about them.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for pointing out the other question. Maybe I am missing something obvious but I do not see how it answers this question. Unless you mean to say that allocatable variables ignore stack size limits.

Comment: They indeed do, they are allocated on the heap.